# How do I create a new Connection in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle11g

I've just installed Oracle Database 11g Release 2 on windows 7.

I'm in Oracle SQL Developer and I'm trying to create a new connection, but when I click in **"Connect"**, I got the message: **"Status: Failure -Test failed: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"**.

In the connection window, I've tried changing the role to SYSDBA, the OS Authentication, the port, and the SID, but even when changing those values I got the same message.

tnsnames.ora contents:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: F:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.104)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.168.0.104)
    )
  )
```

listener.ora:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: F:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.104)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = F:\Oracle
```

alert log:

```
<msg time='2015-06-02T19:28:12.428-05:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='KK-PC'
 host_addr='fe80::986b:9a38:5c9f:fc06%10' version='1'>
 <txt>02-JUN-2015 19:28:12 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=CLRExtProc)(CID=(PROGRAM=SQL Developer)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=KK))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.0.104)(PORT=51332)) * establish * CLRExtProc * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
```

**lsnrctl status:**

```
Services Summary...
Service "orcl.168.0.104" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB.168.0.104" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

How can I solve this?

thanks.

Comment: Did you set the host and port to match the listener for your database? Is the listener actually running, and on the address/port you think (`lsnrctl status` will tell you). Is there a firewall between the database and your PC, if it isn't the same box?

Comment: I've set the host and port to match the listener. The listener is running. I've disabled firewall and antivirus and I'm trying to connect from the same machine where it's installed. I've added the SID on the tnsnames.ora file. I've added the tnsnames.ora contents in my question. Now I get the message: "No more data to read from socket".............What can I do now?

Comment: Not sure; that sounds like a firewall problem still. But check the alert log to see if something is breaking at the DB end - unlikely but you never know. Are you getting that testing/creating the connection, or is it established and you're trying to run statements now?

Comment: I'm testing and trying to create the connection.........I've added the alert log in my question...........What can I do?

Comment: Why is the SID for the ORCL alias set to CLRExtProc in your tnsnames.ora? That should almost certainly be ORCL too - to match your actual database SID. Are you using a TNS connection from SQL Developer? It might be easier to use a Basic connection and supply that information directly; and use the service name (if you know it - that value in the tnsnames.ora look odd too).

Comment: Also, which version of SQL Developer? I'm still not sure how you're generating that error...

Comment: I had added the SID part in the ORCL alias in the tnsnames.ora file just to test, and I forgot to remove it. I've just removed it. I'm using Basic connection. If I use the service name the connection test is successful.........I'm using SQL Developer version 1.5.5 Build MAIN-5969.

Comment: The tnsnames.ora isn't relevant for a basic connection, but could be useful to check the connection settings you are using. I'm unclear how you're getting that alert log entry from a basic connection to ORCL. That's a very old version though - no idea why they still ship that! - and it's probably worth upgrading to the current version 4.1 anyway.

Comment: I've just did this in command prompt: lsnrctl stop..........then removed listener.ora file from F:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN folder........then lsnrctl start...........Now when trying to connect I get: "Status: Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505, TNS: listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor".

Comment: If it's successful with the service name, why are you using the SID? The SID would have to be explicitly referenced in the listener.ora to be usable.

Comment: I wanted to learn how to connect using the SID. What I did is to stop the listener service, then remove the listener.ora from the ADMIN folder, and then starting the service again. Then I did a **lsnrctl status** in command prompt and I got the results that I posted in the question. So now I could connect with the **orcl** SID and with the **orcl.168.0.104** service name. Thanks a lot. Post your answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Alex post your answer.

Comment: I don't have an answer to post. I don't quite understand what you did to the listener in the end or how this relates to the original error in the question. I've you have a coherent picture, you can always post your own answer - self-answering questions is allowed (if not encouraged).

Answer (score 0):

So I'll answer my own question hehe.

What I did is to stop the listener service, then I removed the listener.ora from the ADMIN folder, and then I started the service again.

Then I did a **lsnrctl status** in command prompt and I got the service name and the SID. So now I could connect with the **orcl** SID and with the **orcl.168.0.104** service name, everything works perfect. Thanks a lot.